# Mouse Coordinates stop working after using translation to recallibrate the coordination system-java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am developing a coordinate system whereby the points (0,0) will lie in the center of the panel but after translating the default (0,0) coordinates, the mouse coordinates stop  displaying.Without this line of code  "ga.translate(175.0, 125.0)",the program works .How can I fix this issue?Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    public JLabel label;
    //@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
        ga.translate(175.0, 125.0); //the mouse coordinates stop displaying with this code
        ga.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        GraphicsDraw D = new GraphicsDraw();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("MouseCoordinates111");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(m);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public Main() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        label = new JLabel("No Mouse Event Captured", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label);
        //super();
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getX() + " / " + e.getY());
        label.setText("Mouse Cursor Coordinates => X:" + e.getX() + " |Y:" + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you manipulate (certain) values of the `Graphics` object (like translates, transforms) you should always restore it to its original state.

An easy way to do this is to create a temporary `Graphics` object do to your painting:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D ga =  (Graphics2D)g.create();

    ga.translate(175.0, 125.0); //the mouse coordinates stop displaying with this code
    ga.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);

    ga.dispose();
}
```

Comment: The code works but  the mouse coordinates display (0,0) on the top left of the panel, but I need the mouse coordinates to display (0,0) at the point (175.0, 125.0) after translation.

Comment: @dkchetan, Yes the translation in the painting method doesn't affect the actual mouse coordinates of the MouseEvent. You need to do the conversion of the Point in the Mouse event manually. So basically I don't understand the rationale for this requirement. It adds overhead to all your mouse processing logic.